# Resizing columns proportionally in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table:

```
<table style="width: 398px;">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 40px">A</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
    <th>A longer column</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

The first column is set to a fixed width. I want the other three columns to use up all of the remaining space equally.

Is there any way to do this without specifying the pixel width for each column?

You can see that the last three columns do not use the same width:
http://jsfiddle.net/ztyku/4/

Comment: Your code is actually working for me. The first column takes up 40px and the others are spaced equally within the 398px table. - Perhaps there is something else that is causing this issue...? Some other styles overwriting your element styles...?

Comment: @jeremy: You're right, it was some other part of the code that was messing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not wanting to use pixel widths or are you not wanting to use **any** widths? Percent based widths usually will work in this situation.

```
<table style="width: 398px;" border=1>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 10%;">A</th>
    <th style="width: 30%;">Col B</th>
    <th style="width: 30%;">A longer column</th>
    <th style="width: 30%;">D</th>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Coincidentally, 10% of your table width of 398px is about 40px; which is your desired width.

Comment: I want the first one to be pixel based, and the rest are fine as percentage.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure? What browser is this happening in? This is from your html:

http://jsfiddle.net/ztyku/

**Edit**: I just tried this in the major (modern) browsers and it works. Incidentally, why are you putting `<th>` tags inside the `<tbody>`?

Comment: Chrome adds the tbody tag like that automatically. Thanks for the jsfiddle, it helped me find my problem.

Comment: Since it was a non-issue, I updated the question to another issue I'm having.

Comment: It's not chrome that's the issue, you just need to wrap that area in a thead tag.